# Android GridLayout - margins change on soft key disappears

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I used a gridlayout for a recyclerview. It works but I have a side effects. 
I used an AutoCompleteTextView to add items to a sorted list. When I add a new Item, it has added in the right position but with no margin among the cards. when the soft key disappears, the margins becomes right. I add a gif to clarify my situation and the code I wrote.

**prod_grid.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/card_prodotto_inlista"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeallinlista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageProdotto_lista_prodotti"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_settings"
        android:src="@mipmap/avocado"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nomeprodotto_lista_prodotti"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:text="nome"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBackroundWhite"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageProdotto_lista_prodotti"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**InserireInListaAdapter.java**

```
import android.support.v7.util.SortedList;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import it.coinquilinaggio.roomate.R;

public class InserireInListaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InserireInListaAdapter.InserireInListaAdapterHolder>  {

private List<ProdottiListaInfo> listaSpesa;
private Comparator<ProdottiListaInfo> comparatore;
private ProdottiInListaInterface prodottiInListaActivity;

private final SortedList<ProdottiListaInfo> mSortedList = new SortedList<>(ProdottiListaInfo.class, new SortedList.Callback<ProdottiListaInfo>() {
    @Override
    public void onInserted(int position, int count) {
        notifyItemInserted(position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoved(int position, int count) {
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(position, count);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ProdottiListaInfo o1, ProdottiListaInfo o2) {
        return comparatore.compare(o2, o1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChanged(int position, int count) {
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, count);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(ProdottiListaInfo oldItem, ProdottiListaInfo newItem) {
        return oldItem.equals(newItem);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(ProdottiListaInfo item1, ProdottiListaInfo item2) {
        return item1.getNome_prodotto_lista().equalsIgnoreCase(item2.getNome_prodotto_lista());
    }
});



public InserireInListaAdapter(List<ProdottiListaInfo> listaSpesa, Comparator<ProdottiListaInfo> comparatore, ProdottiInListaInterface prodottiInListaActivity) {

    this.listaSpesa = listaSpesa;
    this.comparatore= comparatore;
    mSortedList.addAll(listaSpesa);
    this.prodottiInListaActivity=prodottiInListaActivity;
    this.prodottiInListaActivity.setSortedList(mSortedList);

}




@Override
public InserireInListaAdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.prod_grid, parent, false);
    return new InserireInListaAdapterHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final InserireInListaAdapterHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ProdottiListaInfo item = mSortedList.get(position);
    holder.nome_prodotto.setText(item.getNome_prodotto_lista());
    holder.immagine_prodotto.setImageResource(item.getImg());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mSortedList.size();
}

public static class InserireInListaAdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView nome_prodotto;
    public ImageView immagine_prodotto;
    public CardView cardView;


    public InserireInListaAdapterHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        nome_prodotto = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nomeprodotto_lista_prodotti);
        immagine_prodotto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageProdotto_lista_prodotti);
        cardView = (CardView)v.findViewById(R.id.card_prodotto_inlista);
    }
}
}
```

**ProdottiInListaActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.util.SortedList;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class ProdottiInListaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProdottiInListaInterface {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private InserireInListaAdapter mAdapter;
private List<ProdottiListaInfo> lista;
private SortedList<ProdottiListaInfo> mSortedList;


private static final Comparator<ProdottiListaInfo> comparatore = new Comparator<ProdottiListaInfo>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(ProdottiListaInfo o1, ProdottiListaInfo o2) {
        return o1.getDataInserimento().compareTo(o2.getDataInserimento());
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_prodotti_in_lista);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    GridLayoutManager lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 4);


    lista = FakeLista.createList(1);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_prodottiinlista);

    mAdapter = new InserireInListaAdapter(lista,comparatore, this);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




    final AutoCompleteTextView aggiungiPdodottoEditText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.aggiungiProdottoEditText);

    aggiungiPdodottoEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                aggiungiProdotto(aggiungiPdodottoEditText.getText());
                aggiungiPdodottoEditText.getText().clear();
                aggiungiPdodottoEditText.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void aggiungiProdotto(Editable text) {

    ProdottiListaInfo nuovoProdotto = FakeLista.createList(1).get(0);
    nuovoProdotto.setNome_prodotto_lista(text.toString());

    this.mSortedList.add(nuovoProdotto);
    this.recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

}

@Override
public boolean setSortedList(SortedList<ProdottiListaInfo> mSortedList) {

    this.mSortedList = mSortedList;
    return true;
}
}
```

I think it's something about the notifyItemInserted() [I even tried with notifyItemRangeInserted()] because if I use notifyDataSetChanged it works fine but there is no more animation while adding the item

[image]

**UPDATE**

it looks like with the keyboard opened there is less space to render the items (I don't know..it's like the keyboard is not in overlay but reduces the screen space)

Comment: Look for this in your activity in the manifest: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden

Comment: I added it but nothing changes

Comment: Does this line `this.mSortedList.add(nuovoProdotto);` really trigger `onInserted` or `onChanged`?

Comment: onInserted..i put a log inside to be sure.

Comment: My guess is that the adapter and its notify calls cannot properly deal with a `SortedList`. Try putting `notifyDataSetChanged()` in each of the relevant method of the `SortedList` callback (instead of the cheaper notify methods).

Comment: As I mentioned , if I use notifyDataSetChanged() it works fine but I loose the single insertion animation. I don't think it's about the SortedList..It looks like the keyboard reduce the screen size and the gridviewLayout dinamically reduce the margin...really strange.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I don't know why, but everithing goes well when I changed android:layout_width="100dp" of the cardview to android:layout_width="wrap_content"